# Are a distribution's higher-order features harder to estimate?

Tags: distributions, estimation, sample-size, estimators, moments

In what sense, if any, are a distribution's higher-order features (e.g., moments, cumulants) harder to estimate than its lower-order features, for at least some distributional families?

For example, I suspect we'd typically need a larger sample for good estimates of a distribution's dispersion or scale than of its center or location.  Likewise, I tend to believe that a sample large enough to estimate the mean and variance well could be too small to estimate similarly well aspects of shape, such as skewness or kurtosis.  Although I've held such intuitions for many years and encountered colleagues who share them, I'm unsure how to express these precisely (e.g., to clarify what "good estimate" or "estimate well" means) and have begun to doubt them.

Finally, four brief remarks about relevant issues:

1. To help discuss this we might denote a distribution's two features of interest as $\sigma$ and $\tau$ with estimators $S_m$ and $T_n$, respectively, from sample sizes $m$ and $n$, and consider properties of $S_m$'s and $T_n$'s sampling distribution.
2. That notation may help to clarify the challenge of metric or unit in comparing two features on some estimator property.  For instance, comparing $\mathrm{Var}(S_m)$ and $\mathrm{Var}(T_n)$ may not be sensible unless perhaps $\sigma$ and $\tau$ are scaled similarly (e.g., standardized moments).
3. For some distributions it seems clear that certain higher-order features are no harder to estimate than any lower-order features, such as a Poisson distribution's variance (equal to its mean) or a normal distribution's excess kurtosis (0).
4. Although I'm most interested in point estimation of a univariate distribution's scalar features, similar considerations may apply to interval estimators or hypothesis tests, multivariate distributions, or vector-valued features.

Comment: Sample means or variances are always computable, because that's just an algebraic transformation of data. However, for Cauchy/$t(1)$ distribution, they are not estimating any distribution quantity because the moments do not exist. For $t(2)$, you can talk about the mean but the distribution variance does not exist.